# lodepng on windows of ogl texture crash

Tags: opengl, png, texturing

I'm using lodePNG to load texture from a png file but the program crashes when I load the texture.

```
char* filename = "texture.png";
unsigned width, height;
std::vector<unsigned char>image;
GLuint texture[1];
//decode
unsigned error = lodepng::decode(image, width, height, filename);
if(error) std::cerr << "decoder error " << error << ": " << lodepng_error_text(error) << std::endl;
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0,
GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &image[0]);
```

I used VS 2010 to compile and there are no errors, but the crash happens when I call glTexImage2D.
My system is Windows 7, with support for OGL 3.3 on the graphics card.

I have another system, which is a Mac OSX 10.6, and I'm always porting the code, and there are no problems with it on the Mac at all. Is there a suggested fix I could make so it will load the texture correctly on windows?

Here is the site where I got the lodePNG files: http://lodev.org/lodepng/

Comment: How did `&image[]` even compile?  Where do you run `glGenTextures()` for your `texture` array?

Comment: Does `image.size()` actually equal `width * height * 4`?

Comment: what do you mean where? in the main program? and yes they're equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you declare GLuint texture[1], an array of one texture handle.  You then bind to this uninitialized texture handle on this line:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
```

This is incorrect.  You are binding to a texture handle that has not yet been initialized.  Instead, what you need to do is generate the texture handle by calling glGenTextures.  THEN you may bind to the texture.  So try this:

Add this:

```
glGenTextures(1,&texture[0]);
```

Before this line:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
```

After calling glGenTextures, your handle (texture[0]) should be a non-zero value.

Comment: thanks for replying even though this question was a while back.

Comment: I figured it's best to provide an answer, no matter how late, in case someone else searches this question in the future :o